# How can I show an extra dependent parameter in a Manipulate expression?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

The following use of `Manipulate` has a parameter from `alist`, which is iterated via the counter `i`. It certainly shows the counter, but I also want to show the parameter `a` in the control area (i.e., along with the manipulator control above the content pane). I don't want to include it along with plot in the content pane.

Only showing it is sufficient. But if you can make it like an extra slider locked to the counter slider, it would be fancy.

```
alist = Sqrt[Range[10]];
plotlist = Table[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 6}], {a, alist}];
Manipulate[plotlist[[i]], {i, 1, Length[alist], 1}]
```

Comment: What about `Column[{alist[[i]], plotlist[[i]]}]`?

Comment: I'm sorry but if that is an answer and you already do `plotlist[[i]]` then it is a simple mistake.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for this workaround. I basically want it to be shown near to the slider or so.

Comment: I gave you a tip abut Animate with a label for `i`, you can put `alist[[i]]` there too, or?

Comment: @Kuba You mean something like `Animate[plotlist[[i]], {{i, 1, Dynamic[{i, alist[[i]]}]}, 1, 
  Length@alist, 1}]`? Looks good, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Animate[plotlist[[i]], {{i, 1, Dynamic[{i, alist[[i]]}]}, 1, Length@alist, 1}]` can do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want requires abandoning the simple list form for  specifying controls and using the underlying `Contorl` function within a `Row` annotation wrapper.

```
alist = Sqrt[Range[10]];
plotlist = Table[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 6}], {a, alist}];

With[{max = Length[alist]},
  Manipulate[
    plotlist[[i]],
    Row[{Control[{{i, 1, "a"}, 1, max, 1}], "  ", Dynamic @ alist[[i]]}]]]
```

[image: demo]

Or perhaps what you want is

```
With[{max = Length[alist]},
  Manipulate[
    plotlist[[i]],
    Row[
      {Control[{i, 1, max, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}], 
       "   a = ", 
       Dynamic @ alist[[i]]}]]]
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using [`SetterBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetterBar.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[Sqrt[a] x], {x, 0, 6}],
 {{a, 1, Style["a", 12, Bold]}, Thread[Range[10] -> Sqrt[Range[10]]],
  ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

or [`PopupMenu`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupMenu.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[Sqrt[a] x], {x, 0, 6}],
 {{a, 1, Style["a", 12, Bold]}, Thread[Range[10] -> Sqrt[Range[10]]]}]
```

[image]